# Old files restored

Tags: files, restore

For some reason my Ubuntu was restored to another date. All the files I have created since that date are disappeared and the files I have deleted reappeared.

I have restarted my PC many times and I could get back my files. Its really strange!

Comment: Are you using two very similar user accounts? Did you log in the guest account?

Comment: no I have one user account

Comment: Are you using ubuntu one? Did you install specific software?

Comment: No I don't use ubuntu one and I haven't installed any software today. This morning I used it and everything was fine

Answer (score 1):

I figured the problem. I have used CloneZilla to clone my Ubuntu to another partition. Without knowing when I boot, some times I enter to the cloned partition and some time I enter to the other Ubuntu.